# Find general term of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Help to find a formula for the general term $x_n$ of the sequence and find out whether it is covergent or divergent:

3/2, 3/4 +0.1, 3/6, 3/8+0.1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only had the sequence:

$$
\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{4},...
$$

You would get $a_n$:

$$
a_n=\frac{3}{2n}
$$

Assuming the sequence $a_n$ is defined for $n\geq1$:

Now notice that for even values of $n$ you have an additional $0.1$, let's name it $b_n$:

$$
b_{n}=0.1\quad n\quad even\\
b_n=0\quad n\quad odd
$$

And for all $n\geq 1$ you get:

$$
b_n=0.1\frac{(1+{(-1)}^{n})}{2}
$$

So your sequence is:

$$
x_n=a_n+b_n
$$

Or

$$
x_n=\frac{3}{2n}+0.1\frac{(1+{(-1)}^{n})}{2}
$$

Clearly $x_n$ has no limit as the limit ${lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1+{(-1)}^{n}}{2}}$ doesnt exist

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling with the second part.

Comment: Glad I helped @Irina